# HTML/CSS Unable to reposition embedded video upwards

Tags: html, css, position, embedded-resource

I am trying to bring the embedded video upwards. I've tried a lot of things, but I can't seem to find out how I can do this.

Here's a screenshot of how it's looking right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtf8m.png

HTML code:

```
<div class="movie">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3TKDCQCTuzQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.movie{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30%;
    margin-left: 12%;
}
```

If I change the margin-bottom value, nothing happens. I've also tried to use `bottom` and `margin-top -%`,but no success either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends if text is in the same parent container as video or not. If in different, use margin -, like `margin-top: -300px;`, but i don't suggest to use this one.
If you have full control of html, move text and video to same parent container, like:

```css
.containerx {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.movie {width: 33%; overflow: hidden;}
.text {width: 66%;}
```

```html
<div class="containerx">
    <div class="movie">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3TKDCQCTuzQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div>
```

After that comes only required paddings, margins etc.

Comment: I've tried this and it worked. Thank you very much!